# Flexible design to replace a switch statement

Tags: c++, networking

I am working on a networking program and designing a Linux server using C++. This is quite straightforward to design the basic structure. I have a packet definition with a header that has a fixed size.

```
typedef enum{
     PACKET_LOGIN_REQ = 1,
     PACKET_LOGIN_RES,
     PACKET_STORE_REQ,
     PACKET_STORE_RES
}PACKET_TYPES;

typedef struct {
     PACKET_TYPES type;
     short bodySize,
     long long deviceId
}HEADER;

.
.

/*more definitions here*/

typedef struct{
     HEADER head;
     union BODY{
          LOGIN_REQ loginReq;
          LOGIN_RES loginRes;
          .
          .
          more types
     }
}
```

Whenever I added more packet types I would have to modify the switch statement to add more cases to handle the newly added packets.

I am using the union type so I don't have to change the entire packet structure. Instead I can add the newly added packet types into the union structure.

However, when I am trying to parse the raw data to put into the packet using a `switch` statement then I have to add each `switch` statement every time.

I think this is not a good design pattern and I was wondering how I can design the structure in a more flexible way.

Is there a better way to handle this (better design pattern)? What about related tutorials or references?

Comment: If you are using C++, you can and should lose all those typedefs. And have you heard about inheritance and polymorphism?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use classes and instead of `switch` use a polymorphic call.

Something like that (pseudo-codish):

```
class Packet{
public:
   Packet();
   virtual ~Packet();
   virtual HandleMe()=0;
protected:
   // fields 
}

PacketTypeOne: public Packet{
public:
  virtual HandleMe(); // implementation for type 1
}

PacketType2: public Packet{
public:
  virtual HandleMe(); // implementation for type 2
}

PacketTypeX: public Packet{
public:
  virtual HandleMe(); // implementation for type X
}
```

and where you get the packets:

```
...
Packet* newPacket = PacketFactory::CreateNewPacket(packetTypeX); // factory will create
              // the right instance.
...
// now handle it:
newPacket->HandleMe();
...
```

Done.

Comment: But won't CreateNewPacket have a big switch statement in it?

Comment: It will. Only one and only once, encapsulated and hidden. That's the point of the "factory" pattern.

Answer (score 3):

Since your code is C style and not C++ style code, I will give you the C answer.

Use function pointers. Something like:

```
typedef int (*ParseFunc)(const char *, len, struct MyStruct);

typedef struct PacketParser_
{
    PACKETType type;
    ParseFunc parseFunc;
} PacketParser;

const PacketParser[] parser = 
{
   { PACKET_LOGIN_REQ, LoginReqParser }
   { PACKET_LOGIN_RES, LoginResParser }
   .
   .
   .
}
```

You then iterate through all the packet types and call the corresponding function. Whenever you get a new packet type, you just add another line to your `PacketParser` function.

If you are using C++ you are better off using polymorphism.

Comment: +1 - although the question is tagged C++ - your answer is a perfect and elegant solution for a C implementation of the same use case, I like it.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, you should avoid `union`s. This is one of those cases :-)

The answer, as noted, is to use polymorphism. The canonical way to convert switch statements to polymorphism is using the [Visitor design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255214/when-should-i-use-the-visitor-design-pattern).

While normal polymorphism, using `virtual` methods *may* help you, there is a problem. `virtual` methods give you a dispatch to the correct method based on a single object (the `Packet`). But, you also depend on what action to take. For example, if you have many `switch` statements, and not one, then the `Visitor` pattern will be preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to ...

- [Replace conditional with polymorphism](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html)

Essentially, you find a good super class, and for each typecode create a distinct subclass.

You also want to buy a copy of ***"Refactoring: Improving the design of existing code." , Fowler, Martin (1999) / Addison Wesley.***.