# Check if parent class is instance of child class

Tags: java

I have one class defined like this:

```
class Car {

}
```

And many other defined like this:

```
class Audi extends Car {

}

class Seat extends Car {

}

class Mercedes extends Car {

}

class Opel extends Car {

}

...
```

I have a situation where I receive a list of all these cars which is defined like this:

```
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
```

In that list there are many different cars so how can I find out which one is Audi, which one is Seat etc?

I've tried to do this for cars for which I know they are of type Audi:

```
Audi audi = (Audi) cars.get(0);
```

This throws `ClassCastException`. How to handle this situation?

Comment: You can use instanceof, but that subverts OOP principles. What are you trying to do?

Comment: "*how can I find out which one is Audi, which one is Seat*" why do you even want to do it? Doesn't your `Car` class have already all method you need from car?

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard, I am trying to get the data for specific car from a list of cars. I am receiving that list from another place and need to process it.

Comment: @Pshemo, no. Each specific car has some extra variables with it's getters and setters.

Comment: OK, in that case `instanceof` is operator you are looking for. But still I am interested what data could have `Seat` which `Audi` or other cars shouldn't have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `instanceof`:

```
Car car = cars.get(0);
if (car instanceof Audi) {
    // It's an Audi, now you can safely cast it
    Audi audi = (Audi) car;
    // ...do whatever needs to be done with the Audi
}
```

However, in practice you should use `instanceof` sparingly - it goes against object oriented programming principles. See, for example: [Is This Use of the "instanceof" Operator Considered Bad Design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841577/is-this-use-of-the-instanceof-operator-considered-bad-design)

Answer (score 3):

Obvious or not, this will do the trick:

```
Car car = cars.get(0);
if(car instanceof Audi) {
  Audi audi = (Audi) car;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `instanceof` before casting. For example:

```
Car someCar = cars.get(0);
Audi audi = null;
if(someCar instanceof Audi){
audi = (Audi) someCar;
}
if(audi != null){
//...
```

But likely it's a bad idea, because generics was introduced to avoid using casting and `instanceof`.

Answer (score 2):

Check with instanceof, for example:

```
car instanceof Audi
```

This returns true if variable car is an instance of Audi, otherwise returns false.