# Comparing abstract classes without RTTI?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I'm designing a poker game. There will be a PokerHand class for cards a user have (always 5 cards). PokerHand has different categories, e.g. Straight, Flush, Full House, etc.

Now I want all PokerHand be comparable. There's a defined order between categories: Straight flush > 4 of a kind > full house > ... For each category there's a distinct rule for comparing. E.g. for Straights, the high card decides. For "4 of a kind", the 4 same cards decide.

```
class PokerHand {
 public:
  int CompareTo(const PokerHand* another) = 0;
  Category GetCagegory();
 ...
}
```

With RTTI, I can implement CompareTo as

```
class Straight : public PokerHand {
  ...
}

int Straight::CompareTo(const PokerHand& another) OVERRIDE {
  const Straight* s = dynamic_cast<const Straight*>(another);
  if (s == NULL) {
    // Not a straight. Compare category.
    ...
  } else {
    // compare high card
    ...
  }
}
```

Now My question is, considering RTTI is mostly treated as "not suggest to use", is there a good way to implement the comparing without using RTTI?

Comment: You could have a virtual function that contains the category, but I think you are going about it the wrong way... And I'll write an answer to that extent.

Comment: Creating a separate class for each of the various poker hands sounds like a bad idea.  There are quite a few of these and they overlap.  Ex. royal flush, straight flush, just plain flush.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When should I use the Visitor Design Pattern?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255214/when-should-i-use-the-visitor-design-pattern)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that the way you are going about this is wrong.

A `PokerHand` is a `PokerHand`, whether it holds a full house, straight flush or a set of completely useless cards. [You may find that you need to have several kinds if you play poker with five cards, seven cards, or showing or not showing what your cards are, etc, etc - but for evaluating what your hand "is worth", you need one class].

What you need is a function that can tell what you actually have. To do that, I'm going to assume you have a `struct Card` that contains the following:

```
 struct Card
 {
     int suite;  (1..4)
     int value;  (2..14)
 };
```

Then I assume we're playing with 5 cards, if you are playing with variable number of cards, then you probobably want to use a vector.

```
 class PokerHand
 {
    ... 
    Card cards[5]; 
 }


 int PokerHand::value()     
 // return 0 for "useless, nothing", otherwise how good -> better is higher
 {
    int ret = 0;

    ... check if they are the same suite (flush)
        ... if so, are they in sequence (straight flush)
           ... if so, is the highest a king - (royal straight flush)  
        return ret;

    else

       ... here we write code to check how many cards have the same value 
           (2, 3, 4  of a kind or full house)
       if at least two same value:
       return ret;          

   return ret;

 }
```

You may find that writing this function is easier if you sort the hand by suite or by value respectively for the two steps.  You need to take into account the value of the cards, e.g. 3 aces beats 3 kings beats 3 queens, etc. You will also have to deal with "equal value, better suite" type situations, e.g. 3 kings of, and using the values of the remaining cards (e.g. 3 of a kind has two "not used cards") to determine the highest value.

There are rules listed here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands

Comment: With regards to `PokerHand::value()`, I'd probably implement it as a sequence of `if ... else if ... else if ...`, checking each possibility in order of rank.  It might not be the most efficient (e.g. you check for flush in both `if ( isStraightFlush() )` and `if ( isFlush() )`), but it seems the simplest to write and understand.  You also want to return a struct, since you need two elements: the type of hand (e.g. flush, three of a kind, etc.), and the rank within the type.

Comment: And a place where inheritance might be appropriate: calculating the rank within the type.  You could have a rank calculator for each type.

Comment: The reason I choose a single return value is that I wanted a simple comparison - although I guess we could always have two functions, one that return a struct of "what is it", and a rank within that type, and then a second function that understands the rank within these. Yes, a set of functions that do `isFlush()` and so on is definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign weights to each hand type and subweights to colours and card order. Then you can have a virtual function to calculate weights and subweights and compare the results. Would that work for you?

Comment: There's not actually any reason for the function to be virtual.  There's really only one type of hand (for the moment).

Comment: That's not the impression I got. You have a (royal/straight) flush, 4 of a kind, full house, pair, etc. These are different hands in the opening question. Of course you can do away without it easily, however my answer relates to the "as is" state of affairs.

Comment: Whether a hand is a flush, or a straight, or whatever, is not (or should not be) part of the type; it's a function of the value of the hand.  As long as he is restricting his game to five cards, there is no need for any virtual functions.

Answer (score 1):

Tempting though it is, given the clear is-a relationship between flush, straight, etc. and poker hand, I wouldn't use inheritance here at all actually, at least not for hand-types.  In any draw poker game, for example, **the type of hand can change**, and in other games like Texas Hold-em it is only gradually revealed.  But of course class type can't be changed after initialization.

Rather just store the cards, and have a base or friend function which returns the type (member of an enum) and another for ordering the cards (so you can get the high card, etc.)  Then define a simple comparator function, again base class or global friend, which compares two hands.

```
struct Card
{
   int suit, rank;
};
bool operator<(const Card& a, const Card& b) { ... }

class PokerHand
{
   public: 
      // ... constructor

      enum HandType
      {
         NOTHING = 0,
         PAIR, 
         TWO_PAIR, 
         ...
      }

      HandType GetHandType() { ... }

   private:
      std::vector<Card> _hand;
};
bool operator<(const PokerHand& a, const PokerHand& b) { ... }
```

Doesn't strike as being that hard to fill in the blanks.

If you're *sure* you want derived classes, then I would go with type fields over RTTI, which can be accomplished with e.g. an enum as above.

Answer (score 0):

That should be quite simple. You can add some kind of weight :

```
class PokerHand {
 public:
  //...
  virtual int GetHandWeights() const = 0;
};

bool operator<( const PokerHand & lh, const PokerHand & rh )
{
  return lh.GetHandWeights() < rh.GetHandWeights();
}
```

Then, all you need to do it to use `operator<`.