# Template Config parameter VS include Files

Tags: c++, templates, configuration

I have a huge Framework, which is currently implemented with config `structs` which are handed to the classes by a single template parameter:

A config struct looks for example as the following:

```
struct AConfig{
  struct A{ 
   typedef Data DataType;
   ... lots of typedefs and other config structs ... 

  };
  struct B{ ... lots of typedefs and other config structs ... };
  ...
}
```

These hierarchical structs contain the typedefs of relevant classes which should be used everywhere in the framework.

I then inject these configs into the classes everywhere in the framework, for example in a file `A.hpp` :

```
#include "Manager.hpp"
template<typename AConfig>
class A{

   //Macro which expands the AConfig  struct hirarchy

   // Implementation which does manipulation on DataType classes
   DataType a;
   a.doIt(); //and so on... 

}
```

The cool thing about this design is the following:

- By using one **single** template argument, I prevent that my template declarations would get nasty long if I would not use these hierarchical config structs.
- I can change very easily the typedefs in the config structs to use other class implementations in my framework, these definitions just get injected into the classes everywhere.
- If I **only** include for example the `Data.hpp` file in lets say `Manager.hpp` (where it might be most appropriate (assumption)) then I dont need to reinclude it in `A.hpp` again, because the compiler resolves this due to templates..(?) That makes it handy if I have another implementation of the Data class in `Data2.hpp`. So if I use the same files for another project which should use the new class `Data2.hpp` file. I only change the Config structs and that very single include in the framework...
- One downside is that compilation time is really high because the compiler has to resolve all these depended typenames  and so on...

I am really unsure, if this design method is a good choice. What I want is to have some file `TypeDefs.hpp` (which contains currently my hierachical typedefs) which defines my whole framework, which objects are used in which classes and so on.
**I would like to get rid of all my templated classes like "A"** because I think its bad pratice?. I want to be able to make changes to the typedef header file and I do not want to change `#include` statements in the source files, I would like that the only file which I change is the typedef file (for example replacing a class Data with another one)

How should I do this in the best way?

  -

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are implementing a simplified version of the visitor pattern. Your AConfig struct is the visitor that performs logic on the visited - the framework class. And your approach is definitely not a bad practice: you admitted that it saves you work. Right on! 
Your visitor-visited separation can be improved and that's in the links and the pointers below. The pattern seems applicable because you have a large existing framework of classes that you would like to keep unaware of the new operations that can be performed on them by the visitor, they just provide access to their data/computations.

Check out [When should I use the Visitor Design Pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255214/when-should-i-use-the-visitor-design-pattern)

And maybe http://rgomes-info.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/a-better-implementation-of-visitor.html

Search for for "double dispatch", boost any variant "visitor pattern".

Comment: good interesting answer, but i dont know if this helps further =), dont yet see how that can be applied. I used the AConfig struct only to hierachically collect "typedefs" for the framework actually (no logic is inside these structs)