# How to get the type of a value (Java)

Tags: java, casting

The solutions I've seen online make sense; if you know the type of the variable, then you know the type of its value. Java makes it that way; however, if I have a system of inherited classes such as this ...

```
DynastyPQ (base class)
FirstPQ (inherited class)
```

And create the objects in this manner ...

```
DynastyPQ pq = new FirstPQ();
```

Is there a way to get the **type** of FirstPQ so that I can use it in a cast so that I can access the class's exclusive methods? Maybe something akin to this?

```
(typeof(pq's value)pq).exclusiveMethod()
```

Comment: No, not without using reflection (which bypasses type safety). It's not quite as per your code, but you could do `if (pq instanceof FirstPQ) ((FirstPQ)pq).exclusiveMethod();`

Comment: @Bohemian Could use a visitor. It may be excessive for what he wants, but technically you could check the type without reflection

Comment: try the     'getClass()' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options.

1. You could use reflection
2. You could use `instanceof`
3. You could use the visitor pattern

For these examples, we will attempt to find the type of this variable:

```
Object obj = new TargetType();
```

We want to see if the object referenced by `obj` is of type `TargetType`.

---

**Reflection**

There are a couple ways you could do this:

```
if(obj == TargetType.class) {
    //do something
}
```

The idea behind the code above is that `getClass()` returns a reference to the `Class` object used to instantiate that object. You can compare the reference.

```
if(TargetType.class.isInstance(obj)) {
    //do something
}
```

`Class#isInstance` checks to see if the object value passed to method is an instance of the class we are calling `isInstance` on. It will return `false` if `obj` null, so no null check is needed. This requires casting to perform operations on the object.

---

**instanceof**

This one is simple:

```
if(obj instanceof TargetType) {
    //do something
}
```

`instanceof` is part of the language specification. This returns `false` if `obj` is null. This requires casting to perform operations on the object.

---

**Visitor Pattern**

I have explained this in detail in one of my [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458676/how-to-avoid-instanceof-when-implementing-factory-design-pattern/29459571#29459571). You would be in charge of handling `null`. You should look deeper into the pattern to see if it's right for your situation, as it could be an overkill. This does not require casting.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `getClass()` method.
This will return the run time class of the particular object.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_getclass.htm

Comment: The question is, how to cast to this runtime class at runtime

Comment: @Smac89 `getClass().cast()`? Note: I have no idea...This is all unknown territory for me, but It's a lot of interesting info I'm learning through the concepts and answers to this question. =)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options:

1. With the `instanceof` operator:

   - `if (pq instanceof FirstPQ) {((FirstPQ)pq).exclusiveMethod();}`
2. With the [`Class.isInstance(Object obj)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) *instance* method:

   - `FirstPQ firstPQ;
     if(pq.getClass().isInstance(firstPQ)) {
       firstPQ = (FirstPQ)pq;
     }`
     (Note: <s>Not yet tested.</s> *Confirmed.*)
3. With a visitor pattern:

   - See [Vince Emigh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34467846/1253136).

Comment: Not 100% true, check out my answer

Comment: @VinceEmigh What isn't (100% true)?

Comment: "*this can't really be done in a dynamic, non-declarative way in Java without bypassing type-safety with reflection.*" - That's the statement I was referring to. Your answer is valid, it's just that statement I found to be a bit off