# Skip instanceOf in this specific case (java)

Tags: java, oop, instanceof

I know this topic has 2 kinda of duplicates by there where TL;DR; use method override, mine i belive is not that simple.This will be basically a theoritical question i wont link the code cause its just to long.

Imagine that we have 3 different types of emergency centers which all inherit an abstract class which implements an interfaces (`FireServiceCenter`, `MedicalServiceCenter` and `PoliceServiceCenter`)

And 3 types of emergencies which all inherit an abstract class which implements an interface (`OrderEmergency`,  `PropertyEmergency`, `HealthEmergency`)

Each of the 3 centers can only take care of 1 type of emergency and there are only 3 centers not more and all are different types, i.e. we can handle all emergencies.

`FireServiceCenter` - > `PropertyEmergency`

`MedicalServiceCenter` - > `HealthEmergency`

`PoliceServiceCenter` - >`OrderEmergency`

The input will be, let's say, 500 different emergencies and just link them to their respective center

How can I accomplish this without using `instanceOf`?

My first thought was to just add an extra `final static` field to each center 
and emergency class  witch I would have called `typeOfCenter`/`typeOfEmergency` and add all of the emergencies in 1 collection and then  all centers in 1 collection and then just match them together (with 2 for loops: 1 for `centers` and 1 of `emergencies`), but I don't know how this is any different from`instanceOf` cause i will be using `.equals` for their fields.

Comment: Sounds like you need [multi-dispatching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29458676/how-to-avoid-instanceof-when-implementing-factory-design-pattern/29459571#29459571)

Comment: Pass the emergency an object which holds the various centers (Say, with a getter method for each); have the emergency pick the center it wants to deal with. (This is double dispatch)

Comment: Vince Emigh ok thanks it seems this topic you linked hold the asnwer i looked of, but of course my habit of not reading more then 5 seconds got the best of me again, i actualyl check that topic before i posted my own,  if you want post an asnwer i will mark it as best. I will delete the topc in 10 min or so.

Comment: @ВсеЕдно It's best to mark this post as duplicate. I'm not a huge fan of rep hounding. If you need help implementing, feel free to start a chat and invite me :)