# Possible to have switch(java.lang.Object) in java?

Tags: java, object, switch-statement, if-statement

My application required to have switch case statement of type `String`.

I need something like this:

```
    Object list1 = "list1";
    Object list2 = "list2";
    Object list3 = "list3";

    Object option = "list1";
    switch (option) {
        case list1: // Do something
        case list2: // Do something
        case list3: // Do something
        default:    // Do something
    }
```

Is it possible to have?

> **EDIT:**
>
> Is it better to use switch case for `n` conditions rather going with `if`
>   and `else`? Please comment on it?

Comment: You can also use polymorphism : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425659/alternative-to-switch-case-in-java/1425684#1425684

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since you are switching on Strings I assume that the strings are known at compile time. In that case you can use an enum.

```
    public enum MyStrings{

        LIST1, LIST2
    }
```

Then

```
    switch(MyStrings.valueOf(option)){

         case LIST1: do something; break;
         //etc.
    }
```

Comment: Thanks dude :) helpful. please see my update in the question.

Answer (score 4):

In the JDK 7 release, you can use a String object in the expression of a switch statement:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/strings-switch.html

Answer (score 3):

See this question: [Why can't I switch on a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338206/switch-statement-with-strings-in-java)

Not currently supported, but expected to be in Java 7.

Edit: actually appears to be `String`s only, not any `Object`s

Perhaps each object should implement a method that contains the logic you're trying to put into the switch statement?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do this (try it and find out). But if you want this, perhaps a Map such as a HashMap would better suit your purposes.

Answer (score 1):

No, use other collections like Hashmap or use array indexes to do the same, create an array of elements and put a switch case on index

Answer (score 0):

The switch can be supported for checking String, Integer and other primitive data types, but it is not approve successful in objects comparisons.