# Java switch/case vs if issue

Tags: java, class, oop, data-structures, stack

I have been trying to simulate **Stack** using java classes.
here go my class constructor:

```
        public Stack(Class<?> type){

        if(type==String.class){

                //...

            }

            switch(type){

                    case (String.class):
                            //...
                    break;
                    case (Integer.class):
                            //...
                    break;

                    case (Double.class):
                            //...
                    break;

                    case (Byte.class):
                            //...
                    break;

                    default:
                    break;

            }

            this.counter = -1;

        }
```

but confusingly for me,
the if block works fine. But with the switch/case block it doesn't compile.

error says

```
incompatible types
                switch(type){
                       ^
  required: int
  found:    Class
```

And

```
error: constant expression required
case (String.class):
```

this repeats for all cases in the switch block.

Please kindly point me whether if anything missing here.

Comment: Wait... The compiler is clear enough: `switch` expects an `int` but you're passing a `Class` object

Comment: *Please kindly point me whether if anything missing here*. Sure: [Java Tutorials. The switch Statement.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

Comment: Apart from the wrong usage of `switch` statement here, may I ask why to have such odd design and not use generics?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza : Thanks for the guidance. We just started the Data structures and algorithms subject. Thought its good to try different approaches ;)

Comment: @shan it is good trying different approaches, but this approach leads to hard to maintain code and not-useful-to-be-prepared-for-real-world-apps. Are you really sure that's what you want?

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza : oops... didn't thought that far though. :(

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza : just needed to build a class design for Stack, that could use many data types. Is there anything bad I did?

Comment: @shan You should really check out Java's [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/). Using generics is *significantly* better than writing a case for every class you might come across. Generics would allow you to use your `Stack` class for *any* data type (besides primitives)

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza : Thank you again. Its true I'm lack of that knowledge. I must read about generics more. :)

Comment: Posted an answer with a kick-off example to implement your stack using a single linked list and the power of generics. It will be up to you to continue implementing the other methods for a stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in **the code** is the wrong usage of the `switch` statement. It will only work for **constant** (literal or `final` marked variables) from primitive type `byte`, `short`, `char` or `int`. Since Java 5, it also allow constants variables of the respective wrapper classes of these primitives: `Byte`, `Short`, `Character` and `Integer`, and also support `enum`s, and since Java 7 it supports constant `String` variables. This is covered in [Java Tutorials. The switch Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html). So, to fix your current code, use `if` statements instead of `switch`:

```
//when comparing object references, use the equals method, not ==
if (String.class.equals(type)) {
    //...
} else if (Integer.class.equals(type)) {
    //...
} else ...
```

---

From your comment:

> just needed to build a class design for Stack, that could use many data types. Is there anything bad I did?

The main problem in **the design** is that you would have to add basically any Java class and custom class in this long `if` list, which will make your code **really ugly, awful and a nightmare even for you**. To fix this, Java give us [generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/) since Java 5. So, you could define your class like this:

```
class MyStack<E> {
    //implementing the stack using a generic single linked list
    class Item {
        E data;
        Item next;
    }
    private Item head;
    private Item tail;
    private int size = 0;
    public MyStack() {
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return this.size;
    }
    public void add(E e) {
        Item temp = new Item();
        temp.data = e;
        if (head == null) {
            head = temp;
        } else {
            tail.next = temp;
        }
        tail = temp;
        size++;
    }
    //add the rest of the behavior...
}
```

By the way, there already is a [`Stack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) class in Java Collections API, and you should not have any class with the same name of the Java JDK API. That's why in my example, the stack class is called `MyStack`.

Comment: this is great. Right at the Point.

Answer (score 3):

Java switch/case will work only with primitives(*byte, short, char, and int*), Enums(*from java 5*) and String(*from java 7*) data types only. Check oracle tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html)

> Unlike if-then and if-then-else statements, the switch statement can
>   have a number of possible execution paths. A switch works with the
>   byte, short, char, and int primitive data types. It also works with
>   enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types), the String class, and a
>   few special classes that wrap certain primitive types: Character,
>   Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in Numbers and Strings).

You can use like following

```
switch(type.getName()){

  case ("java.lang.String"):
         //...
         break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Just to add, ops can refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354662/possible-to-have-switchjava-lang-object-in-java-updated)

Comment: @LUiggiMendoza : Answer updated. I though OP can solve the issue with the help of the answer. I'm not interest to give the answer without making him to figerout the solution

Comment: *sigh...* Please read the comments in the question to understand the real problem.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : There were no comments or answers when I answer the question. So, I though, he can figerout the solution.

Comment: I know, but they are now after your late answer edit :).

Answer (score 1):

`Switch-case` works with primitive, Enums and String(from java 7) data type. So in your case you can use `class#getName` which return `string` and if you are using java 7.

```
switch(type.getName()){

  case ("java.lang.String"):
         //...
         break;
  case ("java.lang.Integer"):
         //...
         break;
  ...
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `String.class.getName()` gives `java.lang.String`.

Comment: This answer needs Java 7

Comment: Now this won't compile since you have to set values that the compiler can take as constants. `String.class.getName()` is not a constant value by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

From oralce site I found this.

> A switch works with the byte, short, char, and int primitive data
>   types. It also works with enumerated types (discussed in Enum Types),
>   the String class, and a few special classes that wrap certain
>   primitive types: Character, Byte, Short, and Integer (discussed in
>   Numbers and Strings).

Comment: What makes sense? How OP could solve the problem with this answer?

Answer (score 0):

That means you can not use class type in switch. 
But if you need to do it for different class types just use default values.. like

```
...
case 1: // for string class
break;
case 2: // for integer class
break; 
... and so on
```