# Perform tasks based on URL content type

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm writing a program that performs certain actions based on the content of an URL. What's the best way to determine content type?

//pseudo code

```
WebClient c = new WebClient();
var data = c.DownloadData("http://mysite.com/download/2938923");
//var dataType = get data type

switch(dataType)
{
    case "pdf":
       //Run PDF
       break;
    case "doc":
       //Run Word
       break;
}
```

Comment: A more interesting question would have been how to eliminate that switch statement.

Comment: take a read of this particularly good answer on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/126475/14357

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the MIME type (returned as `ContentType` header with the request).  This way is standards compliant.

```
string contentType = (c.ResponseHeaders[HttpResponseHeader.ContentType] ?? "").ToLower();
switch(contentType)
{
    case "application/pdf":
        // Run PDF
        break;
    case "text/plain":
        // Text file
        break;

    // etc ...
}
```

- [WebClient.ResponseHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.responseheaders.aspx) property

Comment: Is there a way to check the ContentType without downloading the data?

Comment: @James I think there might be, but I don't know how.  I'd suggest opening another question for that ...