# Can somebody recommend a java 8 pattern to replace a switch statement?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java-8

I have following code:

```
 public class A {
    private String type;
    String getType() { return type;}
 }
```

Now  in many code places I have code like this

```
 switch (a.geType()) {
  case "A" : return new Bla();
  case "B" : return new Cop();
 }
```

or somewhere else

```
switch (a.geType()) {
  case "A" : return new Coda();
  case "B" : return new Man();
 }
```

(Note that I know I should use an  Enumeration in production code).

What I want to achive is that when a new type is added to class A the compiler should flag  all the switch statements that need to be adjusted?

Is there a java idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: If you use an enum, I'm pretty sure java does actually flag switch statements that don't handle that condition, so long as the switch doesn't have a `default` condition.

Comment: I just tried it out. It does not flag the missing enums out of the box

Comment: I'm getting a warning in eclipse when I do it.  It might not be part of the java compiler itself though.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> when a new type is added to `class A` the compiler should flag all the `switch` statements that need to be adjusted?

A good approach to this would be replacing `switch` statements with a more robust implementation of *multiple dispatch*, such as the [*Visitor Pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern):

```
interface VisitorOfA {
    Object visitA(A a);
    Object visitB(B b);
}
class A {
    Object accept(VisitorOfA visitor) {
        return visitor.visitA(this);
    }
}
class B extends A {
    Object accept(VisitorOfA visitor) {
        return visitor.visitB(this);
    }
}
```

With this infrastructure in place, you can remove your `switch` statements, replacing them with implementations of the visitor:

```
Object res = a.accept(new VisitorOfA() {
    public Object visitA(A a) { return new Bla(); }
    public Object visitB(B b) { return new Cop(); }
});
```

When you add a new subtype to `A`, say, `class C`, all you need to do is adding a new method to `VisitorOfA`:

```
Object visitC(C c);
```

Now the compiler will spot all places where this new method has not been implemented, helping you avoid problems at runtime.

Comment: Somehow the switch statements look more lightweight and therefore more easier to understand for somebody reading the code. But I have to admit your answer solves the requirement "compiler flaging"

Comment: A good improvement for this approach would be to store an instance of each implementacion into a Map<String, VisitorOfA>. Moreover, you can load the map from a .properties file.

Comment: @jack I agree, visitor pattern looks tricky to someone looking at it for the first time. I am heavily biased here, because I've been using this pattern for many years. The advantage, however, is that one needs to learn this pattern only once to reliably recognize it in the future. It's like learning to ride a bicycle :)

Comment: The Visitor Pattern is a poor solution for class hierarchies that are expected to change. The GoF describe this cost/benefit of Visitor on page 333. "_Use the Visitor pattern when the classes defining the object structure rarely change, but you often want to define new operations over the structure. Changing the object structure classes requires redefining the interface to all visitors, which is potentially costly. If the object structure classes change often, then it's probably better to define the operations in those classes._"

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget about good old-fashioned polymorphism. Having a "type" field with switch statements in a class is often a smell that indicates that subclassing might be useful. Consider:

```
public abstract class CommonSuperClass {
    public abstract One getOne();
    public abstract Two getTwo();
}

public class A extends CommonSuperClass {
    @Override public One getOne() { return new Bla(); }
    @Override public Two getTwo() { return new Coda(); }
}

public class B extends CommonSuperClass {
    @Override public One getOne() { return new Cop(); }
    @Override public Two getTwo() { return new Man(); }
}
```

If you were to add a new subclass C, you're required to provide implementations for the abstract methods (unless you make C itself be abstract).

Answer (score 6):

You could have a map of string / suppliers:

```
Map<String, Supplier<Object>> map = new HAshMap<> ();
map.put("A", Bla::new);
map.put("B", Cop::new);
```

And your sample code would become:

```
return map.get(a.getType()).get(); //need null check
```

Answer (score 0):

In perspective of abstraction, there is another approach for you to use. One way is via [Polymorphism as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126409/ways-to-eliminate-switch-in-code).

Some simple example:

```
public void EverythingYouWant (Animal animal) {
    return animal.move();
}
```

When it's more about *refactoring* [replace type code/checking with State/Strategy](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-type-code-with-state-strategy) patterns. It's good solution to first consider is there any reason that prevents subclassing.