# Does using a map truly reduce cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: java, testing, static-analysis, code-metrics

Suppose I have the original method below.

```
public String someMethod(String str) {
    String returnStr;
    if("BLAH".equals(str)) { 
       returnStr="ok";
    } else if ("BLING".equals(str)) {
       returnStr="not ok";
    } else if ("BONG".equals(str)) {
       returnStr="ok";
    }
    return returnStr;
}
```

Does converting to below truly reduce CC?

```
Map<String, String> validator = new HashMap<String,String>();
validator.put("BLAH","ok");
validator.put("BLING","not ok");
validator.put("BONG","ok");

public String someMethod(String str) {
  return validator.get(str);
}
```

Comment: Now do it with 20 values.

Comment: upon researching I found a blog on the same, it discusses the same approach as discussed in my answer below. The blog address is https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : yes, the usuage of Hashmap in your case does reduce Cyclomatic complexcity.

Detailed answer : Cyclomatic complexcity as per wikipedia is

> > It is a quantitative measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code.

There are various ways to tackle if-else cases. If-else statements makes the code less readable, difficult to understand. These if-else are also bad as each time you have addition / deletion / modification in the cases then you need to modify the existing code files where your other business logic remains same, and due to change in these files you need to test them all over again. This leads to maintainance issues as well as at all the places we need to make sure to handle the cases. Same issues exists with switch statements too, though they are little more readable.

The way you have used also reduces the different logical paths of execution.Another alternative  approach is as below.

You can create an interface say `IPair`. Let this interface define an abstract method `public String getValue();` Lets define different classes for each case we have and let `BlahMatch.java, Bling.java and Bong.java` implement `IPair` and in the implementation of `getValue()` method return the appropriate `String`.

```
public String someMethod(IPair pair) {
    return pair.getValue();
}
```

The advantage of above approach is, in case you have some new pair later you can still create a new class and pass the object of your new class easily, just you need to have your class provide implementation for `IPair`.

Comment: The approach discussed is clean and enhances ease during maintaince. It discusses in brief the cons of other approaches. it gives alternate perspective which works and is a decent design to avoid `if else statements`. In case of downvote kindly comment, It takes time to answer, I just suggest not for this post for any post if we downvote lets atleast respect the efforts and put a comment, it may happen while downvoting we are not clear ourselves. For easy maintaince, there is so much material on internet, watch uncle bob videos, read GOF design patterns. Its important to take care of the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in your case. In simple terms, cyclomatic complexity is a number of linear-independent ways to reach the end of code piece from starting point. So, any conditional operator increases CC of your code.

*(if OP's question is somehow related to `testing` tag)* However, reducing CC doesn't reduce count of unit test which have to be written to cover your code: CC gives you only a lower bound of test count. For good coverage unit tests should cover all **specific** cases, and in second case you don't reduce this number of specific cases, you only make your code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because the cyclomatic complexity defines the number of **linear independent paths** in the control flow graph plus one. In your second example, there is only one path, the first has multiple path through `if` branches. However, it does not seem that cyclomatic complexity is really a problem here. You could substitue your method like this, to make it better readable:

```
public String someMethod(String str) {

    switch(str) {
        case "BLAH":
        case "BONG": return "ok";
        case "BLING": return "not ok";
        default: return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Switch statements does make it little readable but still all the maintaince issues which we have with if else more or less they remain un solved by using switch cases.

Comment: I think in this simple case it is just easier to read, however I agree with you, maintenance is still an issue.

Comment: Yes but only if we are sure we have cases which are fixed and will not change often.

Comment: Though swich statement does help but its an issue found in static analyses, its about reducing cc.