# What is the best way to create a deck of cards?

Tags: python

I was thinking about making a deck of cards for a card game. I could make a list of all of the cards (I don't really care about the suits), but I was wondering if there was a much easier way to do this.

`cards = ['1','1','1','1'....]`

I'm positive you could make a `for` loop to create 4 cards of the same value and add it to a list, but I was wondering if that was the best solution. I am not advanced enough to know about or create a `Class` which I have seen to be offered as other solutions, but I am open to explanations.

I have already made a dictionary defining the card values.

Comment: I would use an enum class.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I propose you a solution with a basic class usage.

First, let's make a `Card` class:

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self, value, color):
        self.value = value
        self.color = color
```

Then, let's make a list of colors:

```
colors = ['heart', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'clubs']
```

Finally, let's build your deck with a list comprehension:

```
deck = [Card(value, color) for value in range(1, 14) for color in colors]
```

The `Card` class is only a wrapper, just to manipulate cards instead of tuples, which feels more natural.

In this current state, it's almost equivalent to renaming the `tuple` type... Basically, it only consists in a constructor, `__init__`, that sets the attributes of the instance.

So when I call `Card(value, color)` in the list comprehension, so for example `Card(11, 'spades')`, a new instance of the `Card` class is created, which has its `value` attribute set to `11`, and its `color` attribute set to `'spades'`.

I recommend you read some tutorial about OOP for an in-depth understanding of the concepts.

---

Now, you can try and improve this idea, for instance by using a more detailed `values` list instead of the `range(1, 14)`:

```
values = ['ace', '2', ..., 'king']
```

Comment: Do you think you could elaborate a little more on the `class` part of it? I am afraid I do not understand how it works, although I think your answer is great!

Comment: @Mushy0364 I edited my post :) Also, I don't like to do advertising for my own posts, but here is a strongly related question about what I think OOP can bring: [Python OO program structure planning](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41660924/7051394).

Comment: Great thanks for clearing everything up, I will be sure to try this out. I have already made a dictionary with values being stored such as `values = {1:"Ace",etc.)` I will definitely take your recommendation of reading the OOP tutorial. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 9):

Another approach can be done using `namedtuple` from `collections` module, like this example:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Card = namedtuple('Card', ['value', 'suit'])
suits = ['hearts', 'diamonds', 'spades', 'clubs']
cards = [Card(value, suit) for value in range(1, 14) for suit in suits]
```

And you can access to the values like this:

```
print(cards[0])
>>> Card(value=1, suit='hearts')
print(cards[0].value, cards[0].suit)
>>> 1 hearts
```

Answer (score 7):

You can represent your deck as a list of tuples. Which is a lighter weight alternative to classes. In dynamic languages like python, you will often do this to avoid the boilerplate code incurred by defining your own classes.

```
import itertools
import random

vals = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'jack', 'queen', 'king', 'ace']
suits = ['spades', 'clubs', 'hearts', 'diamonds']

deck = list(itertools.product(vals, suits))

random.shuffle(deck)

for val, suit in deck:
    print('The %s of %s' % (val, suit))
```

You may wish to represent the card values by an integer, this could easily be achieved by altering the input list.

Answer (score 4):

```
values = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
suites = ['Hearts', 'Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Spades']
deck = [[v + ' of ' + s,v] for s in suites for v in values]
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses enum class (package enum34).

Two enum classes represent the Suit and the Number with a custom **str** function. The `Card` class takes a Suit + a Number

```
from enum import Enum          
from enum import unique        

@unique
class Suit(Enum):              
    Spade = 1
    Heart = 2
    Dimond = 3 
    Club = 4

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

@unique
class Number(Enum):
    N1 = 1
    N2 = 2
    N3 = 3
    N4 = 4
    N5 = 5
    N6 = 6
    N7 = 7
    N8 = 8
    N9 = 9
    N10 = 10
    J = 11
    Q = 12
    K = 13 

    def __str__(self):
        if self.value <= 10:
            return str(self.value)          
        return self.name

class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self.suit = suit
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.suit, self.number)

cards = [ Card(suit, number) for suit in Suit for number in Number ]
for card in cards:
    print card
```

Answer (score 2):

First some utility functions:

```
import random
from random import shuffle

def RANKS(): return [ "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7","8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" ]
def SUITS(): return [ "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" ]
```

Then a Card class:

```
class Card:

    def __init__( self, rank, suit ):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit

    def __str__( self ):
        return self.rank + " of " + self.suit
```

Then a Deck class:

```
class Deck:

    def __init__( self ):
        self.contents = []
        self.contents = [ Card( rank, suit ) for rank in RANKS() for suit in SUITS() ]
        random.shuffle( self.contents )
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a very useful tutorial for this:

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/deck-of-cards

It may look childish but it contains some really good-quality code

The code it contains looks something like this:

```py
class Card:

    """
    The Card class represents a single playing card and is initialised by passing a suit and number.
    """

    def __init__(self, suit, number):
        self._suit = suit
        self._number = number

    def __repr__(self):
        return self._number + " of " + self._suit

    @property
    def suit(self):

        """
        Gets or sets the suit of a card
        """

        return self._suit

    @suit.setter
    def suit(self, suit):
        if suit in ["hearts", "clubs", "diamonds", "spades"]:
            self._suit = suit
        else:
            print("That's not a suit!")

    @property
    def number(self):
        """
        Gets or sets the number of a card
        """
        return self._number

    @number.setter
    def number(self, number):
        valid = [str(n) for n in range(2,11)] + ["J", "Q", "K", "A"]
        if number in valid:
            self._number = number
        else:
            print("That's not a valid number")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right, a `for loop` would get the job done but might not be the most elegant solution. I've never programmed in Python so I don't know the exact syntax but I could give you a psuedo code rundown of a class that would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Could also do this:

```
card_deck = []

for i in range(3,11):
    card_deck.extend([i]*4)

for c in ['Jack', 'Queen', 'King', 'Ace']:
    card_deck.extend([c]*4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code makes a deck of 40 card with two for loops. The deck is made of 40 strings in witch the last caracter [-1] is the color among c b s d (coppe, bastoni, spade and denari in an italian type of card deck). As the 10th card got 2 digit for the value number it is a good practise to get the value of the card using [:-1] so that it will take 1,2,3... until 9 and 10 when there is this card with 2 digit.

```
class Cards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.deck = []                  # the deck is empty
        for n in range(1,11):           # numbers
            for c in "cbsd":            # colors
                self.deck.append(str(n) + c)  # a string for each card


deck = Cards()
deck.deck
```

> output:
>
> ['1c', '1b', '1s', '1d', '2c', '2b', '2s', '2d', '3c', '3b', '3s', '3d', '4c', '4b', '4s', '4d', '5c', '5b', '5s', '5d', '6c', '6b', '6s', '6d', '7c', '7b', '7s', '7d', '8c', '8b', '8s', '8d', '9c', '9b', '9s', '9d', '10c', '10b', '10s', '10d']

Answer (score 0):

"simple code, deck list with 52 card combinations":

```py
card_type=['Diamond', 'Heart', 'Spade', 'Clover']
card_number=['1','2','3','4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'J', 'Q', 'K']
for c in card_type:
    ...:     for n in card_number:
    ...:         deck.append([c,n])
```

Answer (score 0):

An option is to create one card for each rank and suit using "for loops" and then attributing values, and having all the data on a tuple for each card, and retaining all cards in a list.

I used the following code to create a deck of cards without using class: (please not that the values I had attributed were for a blackjack game, but you can change it as you please)

```
ranks = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]
suits = ["Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades"]
cards = []
def deck_of_cards():
    for rank in ranks:
        for suit in suits:
            a = rank
            b = suit
            if ranks.index(a) == 0:
                c = 11
            elif ranks.index(a) > 9:
                c = 10
            else:
                c = ranks.index(a) + 1
            new_card = (a, b, c)
            cards.append(new_card)

deck_of_cards()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cards = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]

deck = []

suits = ["Spades", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Hearts"]
suit = 0
for card in range(52):
    if card >= 13 * (suit + 1):
        suit += 1
    deck.append(str(cards[card % 13] + "|" + suits[suit]))
```