# How can I make this "Card" class generate a list of Card objects?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a deck of cards for my beginner Python class, and this is the code I have so far:

```
import random
import itertools

class Card:
    def _init_(self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        
value = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'Jack','Queen', 'King']
suit = ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs']
```

What I intend to do (and what I think it's doing), is using the "values" and "suits" to create 52 different possible combinations, like a real deck of cards. Now, I just want to print a list of all of these 52 combinations. So I have three questions:

1. Is all of this correct so far?
2. How can I print a list of these cards?
3. Is it possible to have two different lists that are changeable (for example, be able to draw a new card into a deck/play a card)?

Comment: `__init__` is spelled with two underscores on each side.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the best way to create a deck of cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970795/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-deck-of-cards)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it's correct, you only need two underscores on each side of "init" (`__init__`).
2. Make a `for` loop in another `for` loop:

```
cards = []
for v in value:
    for s in suit:
        cards.append(Card(v, s))
```

3. You can `append()`, `pop()` e.t.c. to change lists.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you are a fan of python generators, you can write your card creation like this:

```
cards= [
    Card(v, s) for v in value for s in suit
]
```