# Refactoring of switch statement calling other functions

Tags: java, android, switch-statement

I've a big switch statement in my fragment class. Each case call other functions that for example download an Image and display It, or inflate a layout and show It. Is It a bad pratice? I've read that switch statement can be refactored in order to have a clean code, but how can I clean this code if I call different functions for each case?

Code example

```
switch(message.type){
    case type.IMAGE:
        downloadAndDisplayImage(); //Download Image and display It in a imageview
        break;
    case type.MAP:
        inflateAndDisplayMap(); //inflate and display a MapView inside a layout
        break;
```

And so on..

Comment: No idea if it should be refactored. Need to see code.

Comment: This would probably be better on Code Review, with a code sample.

Comment: Your switch statement is fine. That is clean code. Leave it as is is and dont worry.

Answer (score -1):

Switch case smells are well known. If you want to have a "clean" code, a state pattern or the following link can help.

[Ways to eliminate switch in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126409/ways-to-eliminate-switch-in-code)

After all, to whom is it a clean code?

Comment: Not sure that I can use polymorphism in this case, I just call functions that mainly download something and display in some view It, as in the code example

Comment: Switch statements are no more code smell than any other feature.  Sometimes they're the best answer, sometimes not.  Adding in a dozen helper cleasses for differnt cases when there's no other good reason to have one is a smell.  We don't have enough info here to tell what the right answer is.

Comment: @GabeSechan I have to agree. If there is only one programmer, then I think everything that he is doing is THE standard.