# Is there a way I can replace a switch statement with actions by using a dictionary and some other code?

Tags: c#

Here is what my app has:

```
private void saveInDatabase(string key, string value)   

 switch (key)
 {
   case "a":
      def = Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value);
      break;
   case "b":
      chi = int.Parse(value);
      break;
            ....
   }
```

Is there a way that I could use a dictionary like this to decide what actions happen with the different case values?

```
   {"a", () => def = Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value)},
   {"b", () => chi = int.Parse(value)},
```

My app has a large number of these case statements so I am interested to know if I could replace them by setting up a dictionary and then some more code.

Comment: It's possible to map a key to a Func but how would you know what the return type is going to be? `dict[key](value);`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when trying the mapping.  I need to return to different things like def or chi.

Comment: And def and chi are available when you build the dictionary?

Comment: this is a pure C# question, nothing to do with Xamarin

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126409/ways-to-eliminate-switch-in-code

Comment: You'd have to create the dictionary in the method in order to capture those variables assuming they are local.  Then it's just a `Dictionary<string, Action>`.

Comment: You use a dictionary to reduce the search time from N/2 to a has which is log(N).  Using a dictionary here where you need to search for ranges will not help unless you can map data to a BIN.  For example it you have floating point numbers and can round number to an integer than a dictionary will speed up results.

Comment: Def and Chi have been defined already and have values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mean you pretty much got it:

```
string def;
int chi;

var map = new Dictionary<string, Action<string>>
{
    ["a"] = value => def = Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value),
    ["b"] = value => chi = int.Parse(value),
};

map[key](value);
```

Comment: It is not so clear what the asker wants. You let your lambdas capture `def` and `chi` which are defined in a "containing scope", but not catch `value`. Depending on what `value` is, it may also be captured, and then you would have `Action` instead of `Action<string>`. If you use your approach, maybe rename the string parameter in the lambdas to just `v`, but keep `value` in the invocation in the last line.

Comment: @Blindy - Could this be changed to Dictionary<string, Action> ? I have no need to capture any value.

Comment: @Alan2, but if you make it an `Action` you'll have to capture `value`; how else would you be able to use it?

Comment: @Alan2, As you wish, if `value` is a field for example, it could be curried over instead of explicitly sent. These are the kinds of details that become clearer with actual code samples, instead of `int.Parse`.

Comment: Helpers.Utils.listOfDoubleFromString(value) and intParse(value) are copied from the application code. Variable names def and chi are just short versions of longer variable names that are defined like App.CM.Selectedconf.newChi.delays.  value is a parameter passed into the method where the switch appears.